# how to enable a linux server to be able to push to github automatically as github ap?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github

I want to create an automation server with a github app which at the end of the day, just has to push a newly created folder (!! as the github app !!) to an existing public github repository. I don't mean pull request but just pushing and when you go into the repo and on commits you should see that the commits are from the github app.

NOTE:
I don't have any user interface except command line, and everything should be able to happen automatically, doesn't have to get new tokens every now and then, but just works independently!!

I tried the following command without any pre installations on a newly created ubuntu server:

```bash
git clone (- address to public repository in https format -) repository
cd repository
mkdir new_folder
touch new_folder/test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push -u origin head
```

nothing happened except me having to enter my github credentials. I can't input my credentials in the long process and I don't want the commits to be from MY account but the github apps account

Comment: is there a strong incentive to keep https ? the historically go-to way for passwordless interaction is ssh -- access the repo through ssh, set up an ssh key both on the server and the repository to allow passwordless access

Comment: its not neccessary but since github apps don't have ssh options, i think i will have to stick  to https. (or am I wrong? if yes, i would be pretty happy)

Comment: you are not understanding what i mean @LeGEC i need my github app to authenticate through ssh or any other way around that...